# Convert measurements units on the fly in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a 100+ products in woocommerce all of which have a description field which contains measurements in imperial.

I am hoping there is some kind of way to somehow convert them on the fly?

For example, 7" x 4.75" and another one 11" x 17" and another one, 11.5" x 17.12"

I am hoping to change it to 7" x 4.75" (177.8mm x 120.65mm) etc.

Is that possible?

Comment: well, off course it's possible! have you tried anything? Also please show the code of the template where the measurements are displayed

Comment: I don't even know where to start. It's just the generic latest wordpress theme for now. It's not in a custom field it's just the generic "description" field content where the measurements are shown.